# Cannot get first message when accessing an Outlook Folder using Python

Tags: python, vba, outlook, pywin32

I use the following to get the first message of a subfolder

```
import win32com.client
import os
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6) # "6" refers to the index of a folder - in 
this case the inbox. You can change that number to reference
messages = inbox.Folders.Item("MyFolder")
message = messages.GetFirst()
```

And while it is working for inbox  but  when I try to get first message of a subfolder

I get an Attribute error: Item.GetFirst
raise AttributeError("%s%s" % (self.*username*,attr))

The folder has already messages

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the subfolder part into

```
messages = inbox.Folders[3].Items
message = messages.GetLast()
```

I tested the numbers in brackets and found that [3] in my case was the desirable subfolder